# wherehas в foreach работает 1 раз

Tags: laravel

Хочу вывести список по категориям, делаю так

```
<div class="catalog__right">
                @foreach($team_departments as $team_department)
                <div @if($team_department->id == 1) class="catalog-tab simplebar active" @else class="catalog-tab simplebar"  @endif data-simplebar="">
                    @foreach($team->whereHas('departments', function($q) use($team_department){$q->where('department_id', '=', $team_department->id);})->get() as $employee)
                    <div class="catalog-item">
                        <div class="catalog-item__body">
                            <h4 class="catalog-item__title">{{$employee->name_ru}}</h4>
                            <div class="catalog-item__text">{{$employee->position_ru}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="catalog-item__attribute">
                            <div class="catalog-item__phone">
                                <a href="#" title="">{{$employee->phone}}<br></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

Но почему то работает только один раз, то есть возвращает только элементы где id департамента равен 1
В чем может быть проблема, заранее спасибо

Comment: Почему вы делаете обращение к бд в шаблоне? Шаблоны созданы для вывода информации, а не "вытягивания"

Comment: @Alpha я понимаю что это не правильно, как видите выше мне нужно вставить переменную в foreach которая находится в другом foreach.

Comment: Вы пробовали проверить какое количество итераций выполняет первый цикл? Сколько записей совпадает с вашим условием? И на счёт этого: `мне нужно вставить переменную в foreach которая находится в другом foreach` это можно сделать в контроллере

Comment: да, он выполняется столько раз сколько мне нужно